# What to do when Google has identified and blocked a page as spam?

Tags: seo, google, google-maps, google-places

I recently worked on getting my company on Google maps because some unknown person marked our location somewhere way off, which caused a lot of trouble for our interview candidates!

So here is what I did:

1. **By mistake** I created a *Google My Business* account and a page on my personal account, and verified it by postcard.
2. Then when I got access to `webmaster@mycompany.com` I used my personal account and made `webmaster@mycompany.com` the owner.
3. I changed a small spelling error in the address and this time verified by our land-line company phone number.

After waiting a week "for the review of pending edits" I got:

> Your page has been blocked since it has been identified as possible spam. To unblock your page, please verify it.

Screenshot:
[image: Your page has been blocked since it has been identified as possible spam. To unblock your page, please verify it.]

I searched Google for this and found [two](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/business/mQV4hzVBUqk) [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/business/GfxfBxf_Tbw) links, mostly suggesting re-verification and/or transferring ownership from the "duplicate".

My problems are:

1. When I click the Verify button, all the it does is refresh the page!! Seriously, it just reloads the page! Is that how it's supposed to be?
2. Where is the duplicate? How do I find this so called duplicate? When I Google for "my company" I get the location on Google maps, but no Google Business Page.

How can I straighten this out?

**Update:** So what I ended up doing was hitting the Contact Button on Google support, then going and saying "My business has a physical storefront" even though it doesn't, and then later that day the support guys called me and cleared things up. However, my page is still "pending review" and has a yellow bar on the top. The support guy said it'll take 2-3 days but can take up to 2 weeks for it to go live.

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If possible, can you add what you did to an answer and accept that so it will be clearer to others, and we'll know this has been resolved? Thanks.

Comment: done and done! @dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was hitting the Contact Button on Google support, then going and saying *"My business has a physical storefront"* even though it doesn't.

Later that day the support guys called me and cleared things up. However, my page is still "pending review" and has a yellow bar on the top. The support guy said it'll take 2-3 days but can take up to 2 weeks for it to go live.